# Is it possible to find the Toronto in the desert?

Tags: albion

As a child, I loved the game Albion. One mystery I could never solve was that if it was possible to reach the Toronto from the desert. Back then, I had the following map (I guess it was in color though and part of the package)

[image: Map of Albion]

The Island on the right was the big desert and there is the Toronto marked. The story required you to go into passage1 and leave at passage2, and passage3 had no use whatsoever, you just ended up in the desert with no orientation points. I tried once to find it and run around for about 2 hours with no clues left and had to reload my game because I got lost.

TL;DR: Can I reach the Toronto by foot? If yes what do I find there?

Comment: Ahh, the memories. I had the same question back then, tried it a while, but failed. I would assume that you could only reach the prison building.

Comment: I also reached the prison building and was stupid enough to release the woman because I believed she was innocent. If you don't release her, run back to Umajo-Kenta you could ask the villagers about her and learn the truth without setting her free x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, looks like I should pay a visit here more often.

First, here is a nice view of the Toronto located in the desert:

[image: Toronto scene]

Unforunately, it is not present physically on the game map, and this image was taken from an animated sequence in the game instead.

If you look at the actual [in-game map](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/albionworld/images/d/d6/Umajo_desert.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160316120418) of the Umajo desert, you will find a valley enclosed by mountain ridges (the crater probably being created during the ship's landing) in the southern part of the island, which is where the Toronto should be located, story-wise.

[image: Toronto crater]

The only way to reach the area is via the underground passage, and leaving it always triggers a scripted sequence, preventing you from entering the valley manually. If you turn on cheats, you will see that there is nothing there, really.

As for why the Toronto isn't technically present on the map, I see two possible reasons. First, it would need a large image stored in the game for it, given its scale as evident from the screenshot. Considering in format in which maps are stored, it would take a large number of tiles to place on the map, which would take more memory. Memory was not easily available back then, so every "optimization" counted.

The second reason is that the ship is simply too big to fit in that area. To put that into perspective, here is how large the ship actually is, based on the surroundings:

[image: Toronto to scale]

It could fit into the area if the crater was larger, but I suppose all distances in the game are scaled down by some factor from their "real" values, so the island would have to be made bigger too.

*Images taken from the [Albion Wiki](https://albionworld.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page).*

Comment: One addition: I'm pretty sure the cave between Umajo and the southern area had three exits/entrances

1) Entrance north
2) Exit which started the cut scene
3) Exit which led you to the southern area without the cut scene

Comment: @Felix Yeah, that's correct.